# oneToMany or manyToOne Doctrine2 relationship

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, mapping, relationships

I have the following situation.

I have a `clients` table and `services` table.

**case 1**
What I want is to know how to make a submit form in Symfony2 (actually I think that if you can guide me only in YML mapping is enough) that can CRUD a `clients` entity, which it can has X `services` assigned to it.

`clients` table only has `id` and `nombre` columns, same as `services`.

**case 2**
Then, once this is done, I have a new table called `task` this new table needs to have the following:

A client for the task.
A service for the task, which, at the same time needs to be assigned to that client, so it is dependent from client select box (I can make this with jQuery)
And some oneToOne relationships which are actually working very well.

If the task has more than one client, it would be great if I could add on the same form using `prototype` with forms collection or something a new client, and of course, a new service if needed... But this is totally optional, what I'm really lost is in **case 1**, because I think if someone could help me with **case 1**, **case 2** will be easy to make on my own...

And of course, I don't know what to use, oneToMany or manyToOne in both cases...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i strongly recommend this:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

but to make the long story short here is your YAML for `case1` if you want a bidirectional relation:

```
Client:                          // dont forget namespace
  type: entity                  
  table: client
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
  fields:
    number:
      type: integer
  oneToMany:                        // each client has many services
    services:                       // the variable to store services of client
      targetEntity: Service
      mappedBy: client              // the variable to store client of a service
Service:
...                                 //same as above
  manyToOne:
    client:
      targetEntity: Client 
      inversedBy: services
```

i didnt understood the case2 properly.

Comment: When I do that, once i generate entities with `doctrine:generate:entities` it returns me this error `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                                                                              
  Notice: Undefined index: mappedBy in /var/www/pge/dev.pge/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/YamlDriver.php line 367 `

Comment: Okay, it works. But lets say I have 6 services, but I want if on submit form I select `client1` then, the `services` list only shows me 3 of thoose 6 records... How can I handle that?

Comment: i think you should read more about relational database and the way symfony2 handles it. but to give a short answer if you look at client entity you will find method `getServices()` there use it to access each client services.

Comment: I've read about it, and I was thinking about `getServices()` but what I don't know how to handle it... seriously, I'm lost on this, normally I was using a lot of arrays and stuff but, Symfony2 is different...